# How can I stop square brackets ([) causing invalid URI errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I use Rails with FriendlyID to allow users to create their own pages and share their URLs.

My routes.rb file matches the page to the user like so:

```
  constraints(Hosturls) do
    match '/' => 'users#show'
  end
```

Unfortunately, some spammer has created a load of junk backlinks to my site which contain square brackets - think www.example.com/buy[xanax or the like. I don't need or want my application to be able to handle the square bracket (there is no user of that name and the validation wouldn't allow it), I just want to throw a 404 or deal with them gracefully.

Of course, the links don't work, but Google crawls them and it seems to make request without encoding the square bracket properly so every one is throwing a server error - hundreds a day at this point:

> URI::InvalidURIError
>
> bad URI(is not URI?): http://www.example.com/buy[xanax

What is the best way to get Rails or routes.rb to ignore these square brackets?

**UPDATE**

It seems, per the comments, that this issue was fixed in a later version of Rails.

Comment: You mean to say, In your `user` model's every user's slug value is `something[some` type?

Comment: No, the validation doesn't permit using square brackets. But someone's linked to those pages even though there aren't users with those slugs, so Rails is throwing the error when it tries to parse the route.

Comment: You can see this issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5688

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing URIs that have curly braces, URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845661/parsing-uris-that-have-curly-braces-uriinvalidurierror-bad-uriis-not-uri)

Comment: @BradWerth That user seems to want to be able to parse the curly brackets, but I don't need that - I just wanted to stop the error.

Comment: Right... But (and I know this is a leap) if you were to apply the same solution but replace the character in question, the url would be parsed, resolving the error.